# How to enforce the presence of a certain element in the XML file?

Tags: xml, dtd

I want to enforce a `<a-special/>` element to occur *at least once* in my document. For such a grammar, a document like this would be valid (since `<a-special/>` occurs):

```
<my-container>
    text <a id="1" type="B"/> text text <a-special/>
    text text <a id="5" type="B"/> text <a id="24" type="B"/>
    text <a id="5" type="C"/>
</my-container>
```

whereas this would be considered as invalid (since `<a-special/>` does *not* occur):

```
<my-container>
    <a id="1" type="B"/> text text
    text <a id="5" type="B"/> text <a id="24" type="B"/>
    text <a id="5" type="C"/>
</my-container>
```

I have tried different things with the grammar below but I can't seem to make it work the way I need it.

```
<!ELEMENT my-container ( #PCDATA | a | a-special | b )*>

<!ELEMENT a-special EMPTY>

<!ELEMENT a EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST a id CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST a type CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT b EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST b id CDATA #REQUIRED> 
    <!ATTLIST a type CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

I know this is wrong but I was thinking about something like this:

```
<!ELEMENT my-container 
              a-special+ ( #PCDATA | a | b | a-special )*                           
            | ( #PCDATA | a | b )+ a-special+ ( #PCDATA | a | b | a-special )*
            >
```

The first part would parse anything that starts with `a-special` and the second parse would parse anything that expects either an `a-special` somewhere in between or at the end. Can this be done with a DTD grammar?

Comment: Yes it is possible by defining an attribute as `#REQUIRED`. Can you show us the DTD you already set up?

Comment: @potame Yes, I know that I can set an attribute as required but this is not what I mean here. I don't want to say the attribute is required but instead that an element with a certain *value* of a required attribute is mandatory. Just imagine `A` is for apple and I want to force that each document has at least an apple mentioned in its text. I am currently not able to post the DTD but I will add it as soon as I am home from work.

Comment: At a glance, I would say it is not possible with DTD. Under some conditions, something may be done with XML Schemas. I'm also think of Schematron, which could be an option to achieve such a validation.

Comment: @potame Hmm.. would there be at least a way to force e.g. an element `<a-special/>` to appear somewhere in the text?

Comment: Are you required to work with DTD or might you use XSD/XML Schema?

Comment: @MatthewWhited No, actually I am free to chose at the moment. I hear from your question that this is possible with XSD/XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint you want to enforce cannot be stated with an XML DTD.

If your outermost element really is just a sequence of character data and empty children, the content-model-like expression you mention would (after supplying the missing commas) capture the constraint accurately:

```
((#PCDATA | a | b)*, a-special, (#PCDATA | a | b | a-special)*)
```

This would be legal in SGML (or so I think, but I haven't checked). But the only allowable forms for mixed content in XML DTDs are

```
(#PCDATA)
(#PCDATA | x | y | ... |z)*
(#PCDATA)*
```

The constraint described would be expressible in XSD or in Relax NG.

If any elements other than the document element are allowed to be non-empty, then the constraint is not expressible with content models in any schema language I know of:  content models function as a sort of context-free grammar, and the requirement that there be an `a-special` element *somewhere* in the document entails a form of context-sensitivity.

As @potame observed in a comment, Schematron could formulate the constraint; so could an assertion in XSD 1.1, attached to the declaration of the document element.

One possible workaround:  mark the specialness of the element in a different way, e.g. by pointing at some `a` elements in the document:

```
<!ELEMENT my-container (#PCDATA|a|b)* >
<!ATTLIST my-container specials IDREFS #REQUIRED >
<!ELEMENT a EMPTY >
<!ATTLIST a id ID #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT b EMPTY>
```

Since `my-container/@specials` is required, it must name at least one element in the document.  Since the only element type for which IDs are defined is `a`, the elements named by `specials` are guaranteed to be `a` elements.

Comment: Okay I see, thanks you! Regarding your last solution: That would mean no other element can have *id* as attribute name, right?

Comment: Depends on what "can" means.  If any element other than `a` can have an ID, then the rule "Use the `specials` attribute on `my-container` to point only at `a` elements" becomes an application convention, not a validity rule, and DTD validation of `specials` won't guarantee adherence to the convention.  It will, however, catch some errors and make it fairly easy to check the application convention (for each IDREF token in the `specials` attribute, find the element identified and verify that it's an `a` element).  So plenty of vocabularies defined using DTDs use similar conventions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use XSD instead of DTD you may just use the [minOccurs](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_complex_indicators.asp) attribute in your element.

Comment: Can you expand on that answer?  It's not clear to me how minOccurs on its own solves the OP's problem, and I'd like to see what you mean.

Comment: he can use minOccurs on that one element with 1 and max as unbounded.  Then that element will be required to exist at least once.

Comment: Doesn't it depend a lot on the context?  If he translates the expression `( #PCDATA | a | a-special | b )*` into XSD as `<choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> <element ref="a"/> <element ref="a-special" minOccurs="1"/> <element ref="b"/> </choice>` (in a mixed context), how will that solve the problem?